# What was the inheritance tax rate in the UK during WWI and WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, world-war-one, united-kingdom, taxes

I've read somewhere that rich people were **heavily** taxed during World War I and World War II. What was the inheritance tax rate like in the UK at the time?

Comment: "I've read somewhere...". Please cite your source. This will help people trying to answer your question.

Comment: I did some research on the internet, and this is what some people have been saying. I have no source in particular, which is why I would like more details about this tax.

Comment: @LarsBosteen: For my generation at least, OP's presumption I believe to be a widely held belief at least in regards to WW2. I suggest we let this instance go. If it's correct we verify, and if it's incorrect we debunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This graph illustrates the top inheritance tax rates since 1900 for four major Western governments: U.K., U.S., France, and Germany.

[image]

For the U.K. in regards the two world wars it shows the top rate changing:

- in 1915 from from 15% to 20% and again in 1919 to 40%;
- in 1940 from 55% to 65% and again in 1945 to 75%